# Ruby - insert into an array based on a percentage

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an object called `TestSubject` which I can use to access the following data, `name` and `percent` I want to insert the name based on the percent, into an array. so for example,

`arr.push(TestSubject.name)` based on the percentage of TestSubject, in this case its `puts TestSubject.percent #=> 90`

This means that this specific name has a 90% chance of being pushed to the array. How ever I am not sure how to write that in ruby syntax.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.push(TestSubject.name) if rand(100) <= TestSubject.percent
```

Comment: Are you sure its `<=` at 3 percent the rand is 54, `.percent` is 3 and it always succeeds - remember, at this point it has a 3% chance of going in......

Comment: rand returns a number from 0 to 1 under the number provided.  So with rand(100), it returns a number from 0 to 99.  With a 90% chance, that means it would be 0 to 90 for a success rate.  Although I suppose it should be 0 to 89, so maybe just < instead of <=.  With a 3% chance, you would need to use rand(100) < TestSubject.percent, which would mean a random number from 0 to 99 and if it was a 0, 1, or 2, it would be successful (3%)

Comment: Is your .percent actually a number fro 0 to 1?  Like 0.54?  In which case, just multiply that number by 100 `arr.push(TestSubject.name) if rand(100) < TestSubject.percent*100`