# Percentage is not working as expected

Tags: ruby, arrays

I recently asked a question on how to insert an item into an array based on the objects percentage as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264524/ruby-insert-into-an-array-based-on-a-percentage/18264568?noredirect=1#comment26787900_18264568). Now the answer is simple, Yet I tried it, I set the object, `TestSubject`'s percent to 3, and ran it using:

```
if rand(100) <= TestSubject.percent
    arr.push(TestSubject.name)
end
```

but with a rand of 54 and a percent of 3, it always works - This shouldnt, **ALWAYS** work, it should **only insert 3% of the time**, same with, **if the percent if 67, it should insert 67% of the time**.

Yet, it seems to, as it states, do it if the percentage is less then or equal to the `TestSubject.percent`.

ideas?

Comment: Can you show some code around this? In isolation it looks like it should work as desired so I suspect something else is wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you have code that has a loop. Can you show the whole loop?

Comment: Something is going on outside the code you're showing us. I think you need to include some results (including the random values) and a minimal piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting rand(100) to a rand_temp_variable, then test the variable <= TestSubject.percent  ?
That way you could debug / inspect the value of the rand_temp_variable and TestSubject.percent to see what is really going on.

Comment: thats how I was doing it, the rand_temp_variable, or in my case `puts rand_num #=> 54`, while the percent was and is 3. while yes, 3 is less then 54 - its suppose to be "insert this objects name into the array 3% of the time" ....

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your .percent is actually a number between 0 and 1, like 0.54, in which case:

```
arr.push(TestSubject.name) if rand(100) < TestSubject.percent*100
```

[EDIT]:
You can test the rand method with the following:

```
20.times do
  temp = rand(100)
  puts "Random Number: #{temp} <? #{3}\t#{temp < 3}"
end
```

For me, it returns very few True values (as expected)

Comment: nope, my `.percent` is 3...legit the number 3. `puts TestSubject.percent #=> 3`

Comment: I edited my answer to show how the rand method works.  It tests just fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and it actually works:

```
require 'ostruct'

test_subject = OpenStruct.new(percent: 3, name: 'foo')
arr = []

100.times do
  if rand(100) <= test_subject.percent
    arr.push(test_subject.name)
  end
end

puts arr.size
```

Sample outputs:

```
5
4
1
2
3
0
5
3
0
2
3
```

Your problem is located somewhere else.